# UIImageView category does not update unless you interact with UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiimageview

To see a demonstration of the problem along with code, please [have a look at the following 60 second video.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13214955/UIImageView%20Category%20problem.mov)

[Here is a simple project demonstrating the problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13214955/Asynch%20DL%20Image.zip).
Challenge, see if you can make the image appear without having to touch the tableviewcontroller during runtime using the category I've created.

I have created a simple `UIImageView` category where I expose an `imageURL` property which when set should then start an asynchronous download. When the completion block is called, I set the class' `image` property to the image downloaded.

I then have a class that inherits from `UITableViewController` where I import my custom `UIImageView` category. I start the download in the `willDisplayCell:` method by setting the cell's imageview `imageURL` property. The image is asynchronously downloaded and is set, but the cell's imageview does not update unless I scroll the cell away from the table, or I click on the cell itself.

I have tried things like `[self setNeedsDisplay];` and a few other things like executing the *setting of the image* on the main thread but all to no avail.

Can someone take a look and let me know what I should be doing?

---

Some code:

**UIImageView+AsyncDLImageView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIImageView (AsyncDLImageView)
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *imageURL;
@end
```

**UIImageView+AsyncDLImageView.m**

```
#import "UIImageView+AsyncDLImageView.h"
@implementation UIImageView (AsyncDLImageView)
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{
    [self loadImageWithURL:imageURL completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"image has been set: %@", image);
            self.image = image;
        }
    }];
}
-(NSURL *)imageURL{
    return self.imageURL;
}
-(void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"set image url request called: %@", [url absoluteString]);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"no error");
                                   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   completionBlock(image, nil);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(nil, error);
                                   NSLog(@"error");
                               }

                           }];
}
```

Comment: Could part of the problem be that the image gets updated in a background thread and any interaction with UI has to be on the main thread?

Comment: @Flexicoder An update
You know in the completion handler where it says `"image has been set"`
adding this `NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));`
You'll see that at first, the frame returns: `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

and when you interact with the tableviewcontroller, the imageview frame automatically gets updated to the right size after...
lol

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13214955/Asynch%20DL%20Image.zip

Here's the project for download...

Comment: Sorry not keen on downloading projects - try changing `self.image = image;` to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ self.image = image });`

Comment: Can I ask why? It's not the full project, only a simple recreation of the problem with only 2 class files with each having only a few lines of code.

nevertheless perhaps you could take a look at this 71 second video then? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13214955/UIImageView%20Category%20problem.mov

Comment: Also, @Flexicoder Just to let you know, the reason why it doesnt show on the FIRST call is because the imageView frame size is 0,0,0,0 (check previous comment from 5 minutes ago) and then on the second call the imageView size is correct when the user interacts with the tableviewcontroller. Is there anyway to force the imageview to be a certain size from the beginning, in a uiimageview category

Comment: Nothing against you, just can never be to careful. Have you tried the dispatch queue just to see?

Comment: @Flexicoder I have. Have you had a look at the video? And then my previous comments? Its related to the imageview having an initialise size of 0,0,0,0.. When I set the image to an initial image from the documents directory, then the initial dimensions are that of the first image, and then everything is displayed. I'm looking for a solution that doesnt require me to initially set the imageView.image property to another image..

Comment: added an answer - @Pavan

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that because the imageView on the table cell is not initialised that the image won't display. I added a transparent placeHolder image (make the size you want the image to be) and use that while you are waiting for the image to load. (this worked for me)

so I changed the code as follows...

DisplayXMLImageDataTVC.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_xmlImageURLArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"xmlCellIdentifier";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     if(cell == nil){
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder"];
     }
    [cell.imageView setImageURL:[_xmlImageURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
 }
```

and your category class back to what it was....

```
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{

//    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(imageURL), imageURL, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [self loadImageWithURL:imageURL completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            self.image = image;
        }
    }];
}
-(void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"set image url request called: %@", [url absoluteString]);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"no error");
                                   UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                                   completionBlock(image2, nil);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(nil, error);
                                   NSLog(@"error");
                               }

                           }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is cell is not redrawn after the image is set. Usually we send an asynchronous request for an image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and after we get the image, we call cell `setNeedsLayout`.

So you can do the following.

```
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)self.superview.superview;

    [self loadImageWithURL:imageURL  completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"image has been set: %@", image);
            self.image = image;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This feels hackish and doesn't make the code reusable for other areas. You'd only be able to use the UIImageView category class in instances where uitableviewcells are used.

Comment: Then the other option, add an imageView as subview of the cell and you can keep the category.

Comment: You can put the content of this setter method to another method and expose it in the header file, since the code is to update the image property, not the imageURL property, setter method should be clean. This way you still can use the category.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that UITableViewCell uses the initial frame of the imageView to layout the cell. If it is not set, then you get a 0x0 frame, and even when you set the image later, the frame doesn't change. If you set it to some placeholder image, then it continues to use the frame from that placeholder image, which might not be what you want.

A possible solution would be to have a custom UITableViewCell, which overrides layoutSubviews and sets the frame according to the image that you have. And from your imageView category, after you set the image, call [self setNeedsLayout]. This will cause layoutSubviews to be called on the next redraw.

You could look at this also - http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/

Comment: this still isnt working. While the frame is finally being set at with the proper frame, the image itself doesnt SHOW, unless again, I interact with it.

Comment: I use a mac, I assure you, I am not a PC. Please do download the simple project. There are no viruses whatsoever.

Comment: Can we continue this on chat?

Comment: I would also try adding a call to setNeedsDisplay from the category, though I would have thought that it shouldn't be required here.

Comment: Sure we can continue this on chat @radical.